# Delphi - Force Component to lay over other Components

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria

I have a Firemonkey Form.
On this Form there is a `TGridPanelLayout`. On that layout with multiple Rows and only one Column. There are several `TEdit` Controls in that `TGridPanelLayout`.
Into the top `TEdit` Control I added a dropdown Button and a Scrollbox with a Listview in it. When I click the dropdown Button I want the Scrollbox to be visible.
Everything works fine, except the fact, that the Scrollbox is viewed behind the other EditFields on the Form. I try `BringToFront` with Scrollbox and Listveiw even with the Edit but nothing changes. I Played arround with `ClipParent` and `ClipChild` nothing helps. How can I bring the Scrollbox and the Listview in that Scroll Box to Front?

EDIT:
Code for FMX Form Unit1:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 569
  ClientWidth = 721
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object GridPanelLayout1: TGridPanelLayout
    Align = MostTop
    Size.Width = 721.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 153.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 0
    ColumnCollection = <
      item
        Value = 100.000000000000000000
      end>
    ControlCollection = <
      item
        Column = 0
        Control = Edit1
        Row = 0
      end>
    RowCollection = <
      item
        Value = 100.000000000000000000
      end>
    object Edit1: TEdit
      Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
      Align = Horizontal
      TabOrder = 2
      Position.Y = 48.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 721.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 25.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      Caret.Interval = 1
      Caret.Width = 10
      object DropDownEditButton1: TDropDownEditButton
        CanFocus = False
        Cursor = crArrow
        Size.Width = 28.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 21.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        TabOrder = 0
        OnClick = DropDownEditButton1Click
      end
      object VertScrollBox1: TVertScrollBox
        Align = Horizontal
        Position.Y = -16.000000000000000000
        Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 50.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        TabOrder = 0
        Visible = False
        Viewport.Width = 640.000000000000000000
        Viewport.Height = 50.000000000000000000
        object ListView1: TListView
          ItemAppearanceClassName = 'TListItemAppearance'
          ItemEditAppearanceClassName = 'TListItemShowCheckAppearance'
          HeaderAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
          FooterAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
          EditMode = True
          Align = Client
          Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
          Size.Height = 50.000000000000000000
          Size.PlatformDefault = False
          TabOrder = 0
        end
      end
    end
  end
  object GridPanelLayout2: TGridPanelLayout
    Align = Client
    Size.Width = 721.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 416.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 1
    ColumnCollection = <
      item
        Value = 100.000000000000000000
      end>
    ControlCollection = <
      item
        Column = 0
        Control = Edit2
        Row = 0
      end
      item
        Column = 0
        Control = Edit3
        Row = 1
      end
      item
        Column = 0
        Control = Edit4
        Row = 2
      end
      item
        Column = 0
        Control = Edit5
        Row = 3
      end>
    RowCollection = <
      item
        SizeStyle = Absolute
        Value = 50.000000000000000000
      end
      item
        SizeStyle = Absolute
        Value = 50.000000000000000000
      end
      item
        SizeStyle = Absolute
        Value = 50.000000000000000000
      end
      item
        SizeStyle = Absolute
        Value = 50.000000000000000000
      end>
    object Edit2: TEdit
      Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
      Align = Center
      TabOrder = 5
      Size.Width = 721.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 32.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
    end
    object Edit3: TEdit
      Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
      Align = Center
      TabOrder = 4
      Size.Width = 721.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 31.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
    end
    object Edit4: TEdit
      Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
      Align = Center
      TabOrder = 3
      Size.Width = 721.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 28.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
    end
    object Edit5: TEdit
      Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
      Align = Center
      TabOrder = 2
      Size.Width = 721.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 26.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
    end
  end
end
```

Code for Creation and Button Click, dont forget to define OnclickEvent on Speedbutton:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.Edit, FMX.Layouts, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.ListView.Types,
  FMX.ListView.Appearances, FMX.ListView.Adapters.Base, FMX.ListView;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    GridPanelLayout1: TGridPanelLayout;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Edit4: TEdit;
    Edit5: TEdit;
    DropDownEditButton1: TDropDownEditButton;
    VertScrollBox1: TVertScrollBox;
    ListView1: TListView;
    GridPanelLayout2: TGridPanelLayout;
    procedure DropDownEditButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.DropDownEditButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.BringToFront;
  VertScrollBox1.Position.Y := TSpeedButton(Sender).Height;
  VertScrollBox1.Height := (GridPanelLayout1.Height + GridPanelLayout2.Height) - Edit1.LocalToAbsolute(PointF(0, 0)).Y - Edit1.Height - 10;
  VertScrollBox1.Visible := true;

end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListView1.Items.Clear;
  for var I := 0 to 100 do
    ListView1.Items.Add.Text := 'Demo ' + I.ToString;

end;

end.
```

Image of behavior: https://ibb.co/pxTcRWP

[image]

Comment: I Added a Example to the Post. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: It works for me when you bring Edit1 to the front.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of current state. It might help us identify the reason why ScrollBox or ListView is rendered behind other components. Also what is [ControlType](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/FMX.Controls.Presentation.TPresentedControl.ControlType) of those `TEdit` components set to. Not sure about `TEdit` specifically but some controls when they have their ControlType  set to `Platform` are always rendered above any other FMX components since they are rendered by the Operating System instead of FireMokey UI library

Comment: @SilverWarior He has provided the .fmx file, which doesn't show `ControlType`, so that must be set to the default.  I'm sure that `BringToFront` brings a control to the front of other controls _with the same parent_.  Using it on the ScrollBox or ListView would not be effective (and my tests confirm that).

Comment: @PhilipJ.Rayment It works with Bring to front in my sample, but I made a Mistake. in my original Project the scaffold looks a little bit diffrent. I changed the Code again, now I can reproduce the behavior again. Problem is I have 2 Gridpanels. Screenshot also attached.

Comment: ControlType is default by the way. Nothing has changed.

Comment: @fisi-pjm.  The same principle applies.  As I said in another comment, I believe that `BringToFront` brings the control to the front of other controls _with the same parent_.  All the edits had the same parent, which is why bringing `Edit1` to the front was what was needed.  Now that you've put `Edit1` on a different parent to the other edits, that no longer applies.  So what you need to do is bring `GridPanelLayout1` to the front.

Comment: @PhilipJ.Rayment Thank you. That makes it very clear. When you post it as Answer I would like to accept it. It works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that `BringToFront` brings the control to the front of other controls *with the same parent*.

So when you have two controls on a form, A and B, and each has a child control, A1 and B1, then in order to bring A1 in front of B, you need to bring A to the front of B.

In your case, you have the hierarchy as follows:

- `GridPanelLayout1`

  - `Edit1`

    - `DropDownEditButton1`
    - `VertScrollBox1`

      - `ListView1`
- `GridPanelLayout2`

  - `Edit2`
  - `Edit3`
  - `Edit4`
  - `Edit5`

In order to bring `ListView1` to the front of `Edit2` and the other edits, `GridPaneLayout1` needs to be in front of `GridPanelLayout2`.

If you had other controls directly under `GridPanelLayout1` (i.e. at the same level as `Edit1`) that `ListView1` overlapped, then you would also need to bring `Edit1` to the front of those sibling controls.